# How can I see the full HTTP request (headers, method, body) in my AWS REST API access logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an API endpoint set up in the AWS API Gateway. I was able to set up access logs for it (I made a role, assigned it, etc). Now I want to be able to see the full incoming HTTP request in those logs - method, headers and body. How can I do this?

From `Stages > Logs/tracing` in the API Gateway, there's a link labelled "List of Log Variables" linking to documentation for log formatting, but the documentation is either obsolete, not relevant to the thing it's linked to from, or just confusing, because the advice doesn't seem to work. They include this snippet (with relatively little context or explanation what exactly to do with it):

```
#set($allParams = $input.params())
{
  "params" : {
    #foreach($type in $allParams.keySet())
    #set($params = $allParams.get($type))
    "$type" : {
      #foreach($paramName in $params.keySet())
      "$paramName" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($params.get($paramName))"
      #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
      #end
    }
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
  }
}
```

This seems to do exactly what I want, but if I copy paste this into the text box in the API Gateway:

[image]

it doesn't work. When I send through a CURL request and look at the logs, I just see the text I wrote copied verbatim:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong template because the above one is [$input Variable template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#input-examples-mapping-templates).

CloudWatch Logs support `CLF`, `JSON`, `XML` and `CSV`. For more reference, you have to understand - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html.

Here is the JSON format example:

```
{ "requestId":"$context.requestId", \
  "extendedRequestId":"$context.extendedRequestId", \
  "ip": "$context.identity.sourceIp", \
  "caller":"$context.identity.caller", \
  "user":"$context.identity.user", \
  "requestTime":"$context.requestTime", \
  "httpMethod":"$context.httpMethod", \
  "resourcePath":"$context.resourcePath", \
  "status":"$context.status", \
  "protocol":"$context.protocol", \
  "responseLength":"$context.responseLength" \
}
```

To understand each of the above field, you have to read carefully the following table - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS, execution logging (which is what you want and it's different from access logging) is not enabled for http API's, while it is for REST API's, for example.

There's no AWS solution for this available (yet).

The best workaround is to use a Lambda function 'in between' that'll receive and log the content, for example in S3 or DynamoDB, and passes it on to the next step in your workflow. Consider using Step Functions for this.

Comment: Interesting, it seems simple to create some property that could extract the Header. I don't understand why AWS doesn't provide that :/